# Chrome: do not ask to update password at a specific site, but continue to ask for others

Tags: google-chrome, password-management

I want Chrome to stop asking to update the password at one specific site, but to keep updating at others. I routinely access a site that requires dual authentication and, after I enter the code sent to my phone, creates a temporary password *for that session*. However, the password used to get this whole process started is always the same, so I have to select "don't update" every time I use this site. I don't want to turn off this feature universally, because I use it elsewhere on a pretty regular basis.

How can I turn off the update feature at just one site?